# Copy only integer from a text file via batch script

Tags: file, batch-file, copy

I have two text file : aa.txt and bb.txt
Content of aa.txt is :

```
======= TOTAL AMOUNT 5937456 =========
======= TOTAL AMOUNT 5564789 =========
```

Content of bb.txt is :

```
======= TOTAL AMOUNT 857439898 =========
======= TOTAL AMOUNT 556443789 =========
```

Now I want to copy only integer part eg : 5937456,857439898 etc from the above text files to excel sheet.
Can anyone help me??
Thanks

Comment: You appear to only want two figures - the first one in each line.  If that's not what you want then improve your question.

Comment: I just gave two integer as an example. As I have mentioned in my question that I want to copy only integer(number). From 1st file i want to copy 5937456 & 5564789 sheet and from 2nd file I want to copy 857439898 & 556443789 and and paste these values in xls sheet. Hope now this will be clear. Please let me know if more description is required. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not tested:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims== " %%a in ('type aa.txt^|find /i "TOTAL AMOUNT"') do (
   echo %%a
   set /a the_number=%%a

)
```

For the copying to excel you'll need jscript/vbscript/powershell. Or you can output the number s in CSV and open it with excel.